# How to have remote desktop on Macbook with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ssh, remote, gui, vnc

I want to ssh into the raspberry pi from a mac and be able to run an application with a basic GUI.

SSH is already working and good.  I thought it'd just be as simple as ssh -X myusername@mystaticip

Then I could launch my program via the command line and a pretty window would pop up.

Go the tightvnc route? There doesn't seem to be a tightvnc client for mac?

Comment: If you have X11 installed on the Mac it should work with the -X option.  Try running for example xterm or xeyes.

Comment: Should be asked on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 14):

To make the answer a little more explicit, here are all the steps I took to get it working:

## On the raspberry pi

Install tightvnc server (designed to support lower bandwidth)

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Configure vnc desktop with screen resolution and color depth

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 800x600 -depth 24
```

## On the mac

Enable the native vnc client on the mac:

```
System Preferences >> Sharing >> Screen Sharing
```

Open vnc via the terminal (the default port is 5901 I guess)

```
open vnc://myUsername@rpiIpAddress:5901
```

Note that you will have to start tightvnc server on the raspberry pi (or ensure that it's running) before you can accept anything on the client side.

## On the raspberry pi

```
tightvncserver
```

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work for DAYS using both `Microsoft RDP` and `VNC Viewer` and I always get a blank black screen and I can't even see `lxtask` from ctrl+alt+del. For whatever reason, running vnc from command line works. Excellent!

Comment: @Jacksonkr its linux, what did you expect? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use xrdp.This tool is easy to use and there are also some clients for mac.

### To install on the Raspberry Pi

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

### on the mac, use this software:

1. [MS-RDP-Client](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12)
2. [cord](http://cord.sourceforge.net/)

*for german user, there is a tutorial*

*www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-tutorial-xrdp-remote-desktop-verbindung-windows-android-ios-linux-mac-osx*

Answer (score 1):

You can use any VNC client on the Mac.
The easiest is to use OS X Screen Sharing

Enter  `open vnc://pi@IP:5901` at the terminal prompt.

It is easier if you create shared keys, and put the public key on the Pi.

There is a little setting up for `tightvncserver` on the Pi to make it easier