# Mac El Capitan X11 Forwarding not working

Tags: remote, xorg

When I bought my Pi couple of months ago, I had a set up going where I didn't need any external monitor to work on the Pi while on the go with my Macbook Pro.

I'm usually in the Commandline, but I got X11 forwarding working back then with the following:

1. Enabling X11Forwarding in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

> X11Forwarding yes
>   X11DisplayOffset 10

2. SSH into Pi with `ssh -x @
3. Start X11 Forwarding with `/etc/X11/Xsession`

Back then I was on Mountain Lion, and downloaded XQuartz, step (3) worked.

Just got a new MBP running El Capitan, and for whatever reason, step (3) above causes the Pi to pause for a sec, and do nothing, i.e. it looks like the command was executed, and shows command line again for the next command.

Where could I find X11 logs to diagnose this issue?  The Xorg logs aren't updated for the X11 forwarding (that I could see).

Or better yet, has anyone got X11 forward working on El Capitan?

## Update

For the same purpose, the workaround was tightvnc following [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/how-to-have-remote-desktop-on-macbook-with-raspberry-pi)

Comment: This might have something to do with lack of X11 on El Capitan. This question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Milliways. Could you elaborate? A link maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you have XQuartz installed, and do `ssh -X` to another computer, XQuartz will start automatically. You can then start X applications in the ssh window, and they'll open on the Mac. You don't need to do the forwarding bits (steps 1 & 3).

Also note, you wrote `ssh -x`, which means **disable** tunnelling.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained by Apple here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341

X11 is no longer included in El Capitan, but Apple supports the XQuartz project.